# What is the efficient way to keep a duplicated record and delete all its duplicates?

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, sql-delete

This query sounded like very easy but in case of implementation it din sound as easy as it looked.

My approach is

```
   Delete from
    Table where id IN(
   Select id from 
   ( Select id, 
   row_number() 
 Over (partition by id
   Order by id 
  ) as 
   Rn
   from
  Table )where rn>1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, this would often be handled using [`rowid`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm):

```
delete from t
    where rowid not in (select min(rowid) from t group by id);
```

If you have an index on `id`, I would phrase this as:

```
delete from t
    where rowid <> (select min(rowid) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

EDIT:

The only standard way to accomplish this is to empty the table and re-insert the data.  And even this has tweaks depending on the database.

```
create table t_temp as
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;

alter table t_temp drop column seqnum;

truncate table t;   -- back it up first!

insert into t
    select *
    from t_temp;
```

This is also worth considering if you have lots of duplicates.  If you are deleting a significant portion of the rows, then this can be more efficient.

Note:  Not all databases support `create table as`.  Those that don't often support `select into` instead.

Comment: And gordon this would be standard for all datanases?

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja . . . Not at all.  The question is tagged Oracle, so this is an Oracle answer.  If you have a question about another database, then ask a *new* question.

Comment: No.. I mean i have multiple databases that would need the same logic so thought of if theres some standard as well

Comment: @Himanshu Ahuja: The "standard" across all RDBMS would be to have a unique constraint on the column and thus not be able to produce duplicates in the first place.

Comment: One problem with this "standard" way is that someone might try to access table `t` after you've started creating `temp_t` but before you've completed restoring the data.  That someone could get errors and/or could lose data.  And you cannot lock `t` for the duration due to the `truncate` (and the `alter`, I guess, for that matter).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am sorry, I didn't understand your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` as following:

```
Delete from table_name t
Where exists 
      (Select 1
         From table_name t1
        Where t.id = t1.id
          And t.rowid > t1.rowid)
```

Cheers!!